# Get documents which expired before today in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using **MongoDB 2.6** and I'm making a query that filter the documents by expired date. I want to know which documents expired before today. My persisted data represent publications.

I've made some queries but it doesn't return documents. I know there are many documents who satisfy this condition.

I tried two query but no one works:

1.

```
{
"domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate": { $gte : {
 $currentDate: {
    lastModified: true,
    "cancellation.date": { $type: "timestamp" }
 }}}    
}
```

2.

```
{
"domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate": { $gte : new Date()}    
}
```

Part of document records:

```
{
    "_id" : "1234546",
    "fields" : {
        "Orchestration" : "default",
        "Segmentation" : "PFI",
        "MatchKey" : "1",
        "UserID" : "001"
    },
    "domain" : {
        "ApplicationCase" : {
            "_id" : null,
            "fields" : {
                "ExpireDate" : "2015-11-13T13:47:26Z",
....
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post your some collection records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get records which are expired **before** today then you should use `$lte` instead of `$gte`:

```
db.myCollection.find({
  "domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate": { $lte : new Date()}    
})
```

**Update:**

So the core problem with your documents is that, the value of `domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate` are not in the date format instead they are in simple String format.

So you first need to convert them to the date in order for the query to work since you are comparing an String with the Date.

Probably, you can use a code like this to convert the string to the date:

```
db.myCollection.find({
    "domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate": {$exists: true}
}).snapshot().forEach(function(record) {
    var stringValue = record.domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate;

    db.myCollection.update({_id: record._id}, {$set: {
          "domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate": ISODate(stringValue)
    }});
})
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that ExpireDate use ISoDate format, it should works

Comment: But the example you pasted shows: `"ExpireDate" : "2015-11-13T13:47:26Z",` instead it should be `"ExpireDate" : ISODate("2015-11-13T13:47:26Z"),`

Comment: I got ``uncaught exception: invalid ISO date``

Comment: Log the raw string date before update like `print(stringValue)`. Some of your date must be in the invalid format.

Comment: Some application hasn't that field and I got ``TypeError: record.domain.ApplicationCase has no properties (shell):2``

Comment: Not sure if this query works correctly as it will get all the documents even those with today's expiry date, for example documents whose `"domain.ApplicationCase.fields.ExpireDate"` value is say `ISODate("2016-01-22T13:47:26Z")` will also be returned since `ISODate("2016-01-22T13:47:26Z") < new Date()`